# Solve $(1-(-a*\ln(bx))^n)x=\delta$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

Should be a simple question, but don't know how to solve this: Given $a,b,x,\delta>0$ with $\ln(bx)<0$, I want to solve $$(1-(-a*\ln(bx))^n)x=\delta$$ for $x$, where $n\in\mathbb N$. How do I approach this?

As suggested in the comments, we may set $A:=-(-a)^d$, $t:=xb$ and $B:=\delta b$ so that the equation reads $$t(1+A\ln^n(t))=B,$$ which we could try to solve for $t$.

I'm especially interested in $n=2$, if that's easier to solve.

Comment: This is a nonlinear equation with 4 parameters, that doesn’t even use x for the unknown. I would restrain the argument of logarithm to positive, then try solving for even n. Or odd, whichever equation seems easier to start with. Also note if right side is zero then zero is a solution. Next I’ll post everything on this forum, showing what I’ve tried and where it took me. Or leave it the way you put it and expect downvotes.

Comment: @WindSoul Renamte $\varepsilon$ to $x$. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @WindSoul And the argument of the logarithm, which is $bx$ now, *is* positive.

Comment: @TymaGaidash That's similar to what I've tried, but since I wasn't able to proceed from there I didn't thought it would be helpful to write it down here

Comment: @TymaGaidash This sounds quite complicated; is it even easier for $n=2$? Let me give a short motivation: The left-hand side of the equation is an upper bound on a quantity which I was able to derive. Now, I simply want to choose the parameter $x$ such that this bound is $\le\delta$ for a given $\delta>0$ (so I don't need equality). Maybe this simplifies things.

Answer (score 2):

$$t(1+A\log^n(t))=B$$ Let $t=e^y$ and assumue $y>0$
$$e^y \left(A y^n+1\right)=B\quad \implies \quad e^{-y}=\frac{A y^n+1}{B}$$ that is to say
$$e^{-y}=\frac A B \prod_{k=1}^n (y-r_i)$$ the $r_i$ being the solutions of $A y^n+1=0$.

In principle, the solution could be given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually need to compute $x$ (or $t$, in the rephrased formulation of the problem) numerically and I don't necessarily need "$=B$", but "$\le B$" (though it would be nice if it is at least close to $B$). Any idea how to this easily?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that your solutions $r_i$ are complex, aren't they. For example, if $n=2$, then they are $r_\pm=\pm\frac{\rm i}{\sqrt A}$. But I need $x$ to be real (and positive).

Comment: And if $n=1$, then the solution is $r=-\frac1A$. In contradiction to your assumption $y>0$ (since $A>0$).

Comment: @TymaGaidash Is your comment a response to the author of the post or to me? If for me: This seems rather complicated. Maybe the problem is easier when we replace "$=B$" by "$\le B$", which is all I need. The left-hand side should be close to $B$ though. I need to compute this numerically in a performance critical code section and so computing a series seems to be too complex.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Not to you

Answer (score 1):

$$t(A\ln^N(t)+1)=B\iff w=e^\frac{2\pi i m}N\sqrt[N]{\frac BAe^{-w}-\frac 1A},m=0,\dots,N$$

Using  [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$t_k=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^\frac{2\pi i m n}N}{A^\frac nN n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(B e^{-w}-1\right)^\frac nN\right|_0\right)$$

Binomial series for $|t|<|B|$ and evaluating derivatives gives:

$$\bbox[2px,border:2px dashed gray ]{t_m=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\frac nN}k\frac{(-1)^kB^{\frac nN-k}}{A^\frac nNn!} \left(k-\frac nN\right)^{n-1} e^\frac{2\pi i mn}N\right)}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=t+%285+ln%28t%29%5E3%2B1%29-3.2%2C+t%3Dexp%28sum%5Bexp%282pi+i+n%2F3+%29%2F5%5E%28n%2F3.0%29%2Fn%21+sum%5Bbinom%28n%2F3%2C+k%29%283.2%29%5E%28n%2F3-k%29+%28k+-+n%2F3%29%5E%28n-1%29+%28-1%29%5E%28k%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C40%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Bt+%285+log%5E3%28t%29+%2B+1%29+-+3.2%2C+t+%3D+0.580865+%2B+0.64961+i%7D)

Comment: No multivariable lambert function needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't the solution then still complex? And unfortunately this expression is really complicated. I'd really like to simplify things by not solving for equality, but obtain a sufficient sharp bound. Do you think that's possible? (Upvoted your answer)

Comment: @0xbadf00d Just set $m=0$ for the real solution [like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=t+%285+ln%28t%29%5E3%2B1%29-3.2%2C+t%3Dexp%28sum%5B1%2F5%5E%28n%2F3.0%29%2Fn%21+sum%5Bbinom%28n%2F3%2C+k%29%283.2%29%5E%28n%2F3-k%29+%28k+-+n%2F3%29%5E%28n-1%29+%28-1%29%5E%28k%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C40%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B-3.2+%2B+t+%281+%2B+5+Log%5Bt%5D%5E3%29%2C+t+%3D%3D+1.73715%7D). You can truncate the sum at $1\le n\le 20,0\le k\le 20$ for a fairly sharp approximation, but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-(-a\ln(bx))^n)x=\delta$$
$$-(-a)^n\ln(bx)^nx+x=\delta$$

We see, this is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($\ln(bx),x$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function over a non-discrete domain directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We want to try to solve the equation in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

$$(1-(-a\ln(bx))^n)x=\delta$$
$$x-(-a\ln(bx))^nx=\delta$$
$$x-(-a)^n\ln(bx)^nx=\delta$$
$x\to\frac{e^t}{b}$:
$$-\frac{(-a)^nt^n-1}{b}e^t=\delta$$

We see, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$((-a)^nt^n-1)e^t=-b\delta$$
$$\left(t^n-\frac{1}{(-a)^n}\right)e^t=-\frac{b}{(-a)^n}\delta$$
$$(t-t_1)(t-t_2)...(t-t_n)e^t=-\frac{b}{(-a)^n}\delta$$

$t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ are the solutions of the equation $t^n-\frac{1}{(-a)^n}=0$.
$$t=W\left(^{t_1,t_2,...,t_n}_{};-\frac{b}{(-a)^n}\delta\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{b}e^{W\left(^{t_1,t_2,...,t_n}_{};-\frac{b}{(-a)^n}\delta\right)}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.
$\ $

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)